# Need to replug USB device after reboot of Samsung s5e

Tags: usb, shell, usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go

Im using a Samsung tabs5e rooted as the media center in my car. I've connected it as follows:
TabS5e - USB Hub
USB Hub - DAC/Amp (via USB)
Dac/Amp - Car via aux

Now, my issue is that when I initially boot the tab, I need to either cut power and restart the hub that way, or plug out the tab and plug it back in, both of which fixes the issue that audio isn't routed through the usb connection. The usb hub is powered via the car, so when reconnecting the tablet, it's power supply is still on. This makes me conclude that the tab is the issue.

I've tried using set prop commands via shell that I've found on here, but couldn't find one that suits my device. I've tried binding/unbinding the driver and setting every possible USB default setting. No joy.
Any idea on how I can accomplish this?
A reset of the USB port would be optimal, or cycling it off to on so it detects the hub.